# Im testing with selenium on ubuntu. Test in invisible workspace

Tags: unit-testing, ubuntu, selenium

Im testing my code with selenium RC. And every time when i run tests, selenium starts a browser in my active workspase, and i don't like this way. how can i set a selenium workspase to run selenium browsers in another workspace?

Comment: Active workspace ? Do you mean desktop ?

Comment: yes sure in linux workspace=desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For repetitive testing, you should consider using [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) for having a headless selenium. We've branched it to hudson for CIT

There's a [maven plugin available](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/xvfb-mojo.html), for example